# "The specified command ("completion") is invalid" message after open Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I've been working with Angular, but now everytime I open the Terminal it gets me the message:

```
The specified command ("completion") is invalid. For a list of available options, run "ng help". Did you mean "analytics"?
```

I'm not opening the terminal on a specific directory so I don't know why is this message showing in /home

Comment: You've followed some out-of-date instructions you haven't told us about. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50194674/ng-completion-no-longer-exists

Comment: @MartinThornton Thank you so much it solved the issue :D

Answer (score 22):

To solve this problem:

1. Edit `~/.bashrc` file by run this command: `vim ~/.bashrc`
2. Find line which has this text `ng completion script` and comment it, you will probably find it at end of file like this:

[image]

3. Restart terminal then you will not see this message again.

Comment: It's `~/.zshrc` file for mac

Comment: This only solves the symptom by deactivating the autocompletion feature. The underlying issue is the old version of Angular, updating it solves not only the symptom but the cause as well. See the answer by Blü instead.

Comment: This solves the problem for those who uses different version of angular/cli under NVM, thank you for this.

Answer (score 15):

As of angular 14, ng completion from angular 6 was added back, in my case, the problem came from my global angular cli version still being on version 13, thus not having the command

you can verify the global version by doing this on version 13 and below

```bash
ng --version
```

and you can update your global version to angular 14 by doing

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@14
```

Answer (score 1):

Install `ng` globally:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have added the **ng completion** command in your shell configuration file, try to find it and remove it, it should be a line(s) as follows:

```
ng completion
```

configuration file examples:
**~/.zshrc**
**~/.bashrc**
**~/.profile**
..